# Make a three column responsive Masonry grid

Tags: responsive-design, masonry, imagesloaded

**THIS IS A SELF Q&A**

Often my creative director's ask to build a Masonry powered grid, but to make it responsive. Then [new version of Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#percentposition) can do this, but with variable height images, the initial layout looks broken. The solution is the [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) plugin, but it's not immediately clear the best way to apply this to a grid, specially if that grid is generated by a CMS (WordPress in my case).

So my questions is, how best to make a responsive Masonry grid, that is 3 colomns wide, and looks good on initial load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a 3 column responsive grid, with 25px gutter around each block. I this possible to make this gutter responsive/variable too.

Obviously you need to include the Masonry and imagesLoaded JS files on your page.

Your HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block">
        <img src="example.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS would be this:

```
.block {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: calc(33.33% - 17px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.block img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And the JS would be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Init Masonry
    var opts = {
        itemSelector: '.block',
        columnWidth: '.block',
        gutter: 25,
        percentPosition: true,
        transitionDuration: 0
    }
    var $grid = jQuery('.grid').masonry(opts);        

    // Position and show image as it loads
    jQuery('.grid').imagesLoaded().progress(function(imgLoadData, elem ){
        jQuery(elem.img).closest('.block').css('opacity', 1);
        $grid.masonry('layout');
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Isotope instead of Masonry, as its more advanced! and it is quite similar to masonry, your HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

if you want 3 columns then the CSS would be this:

```
.item {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
}

.item img {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

and then in the JS you need to initialize Isotope and also update the layout when an image gets loaded, you would need the help of the imagesLoaded plugin, it should look something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     // Initialize Isotope

     $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        percentPosition: true,
     });

     // Refresh the layout of the grid each time an image gets loaded

     $('.grid').imagesLoadedMB().progress( function() {
        $('.grid').isotope('layout');
    });

});
```

I personally I would prefer to use a plugin ready to use, like this one: https://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-portfolio-responsive-grid/5683020 with this plugin you can specify very easy the space between the items, number of columns on each resolution, and more, also it comes with the ability to add filters, sorting and a search filed, give it a try!